# How to set attributes using vue-test-utils on shallowMount?

Tags: vue.js, testing, attributes, vue-test-utils

I want to test methods in my `Vue` component, but I need to mock some attributes data for that, that I will access later on as `this.$attrs.pattern` etc... My current code is:

```
let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
   wrapper = shallowMount(Input);
});

afterEach(() => {
   wrapper.destroy();
});

it('should pass pattern check', () => {
   // I want to setup pattern attribute here
   expect(wrapper.vm.passPatternCheck).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I was expecting there to be something like `wrapper.setProps()`, but can't find it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there's no support yet for adding later `attrs` to `wrapper`. So I had to remove `beforeEach` and instead do `shallowMount` with specific `attrs` for every test I've done. Looks something like this:

```
let wrapper;

afterEach(() => {
   wrapper.destroy();
});

it('should pass pattern check', () => {
   wrapper = shallowMount(Input,{
      attrs: {
          pattern: regex,
          }});
   expect(wrapper.vm.passPatternCheck).toBeTruthy();
});
```

It would be really nice if there will be support to add later `attrs` just like `props: wrapper.setProps({})`